# Como utilizar CSS externo em uma aplicação JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Estou fazendo um aplicativo com JavaFX e gostaria de colocar o CSS em arquivo externo, por exemplo, o arquivo ficaria localizado no diretório "C:\app\css".

É possível reconhecer o arquivo externo?

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a instancia da classe `Scene`, exemplo:

```
Scene cena = new Scene(Parent);
cena.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Caminho_Para_O_Arquivo"));
```

se assim não der certo tente assim:

```
cena.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Caminho_Para_O_Arquivo").toExternalForm());
```